# Setting FolderBrowserDialog.ShowNewFolderButton to true does not show the "New Folder" button

Tags: c#, winforms, folderbrowserdialog

```
using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
    fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = true; 

    DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
 
    ...
```

The dialog looks like the following. Note that there is no "New Folder" button.
[image]

Comment: It used to be a button, but the legacy dialog never won any usability awards.  Consider clicking on "New folder" in the dialog's toolbar.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant. I'm new to Winforms/C#. Could you point me to the "modern" version of the choose folder dialog box?

Comment: You are looking at it.  Win11 I presume.  These dialogs are implemented by the operating system, not the .net framework.

Comment: Ah... sorry I thought by using the word "legacy" you meant there was a newer version. Thank you!